# How can I clean up the debris from a disconnected dryer vent hose?

Tags: dryer

I have a dryer vent on the outside of the house but the dryer hose disconnected in the crawlspace without my knowledge.  It appears to have been this way for quite sometime and there is a lot of dust/lint clean-up necessary in the crawlspace.  Can anyone tell me the best way to clean this up?

Comment: It's just cleaning. I'd use a broom and/or vacuum. What's the question?

Comment: It's going to be mostly lint, since the washing machine will have removed the dirt.